# Dimension error in neural network while implementing image segmentation using python

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, keras, neural-network

[image]I am trying to run a mask r cnn tutorial to try image segmentation. However I am getting an errro while executing the program. I am running this on aws in an ec2 instance. I am new to AI and have a basic idea about neural networks. So I am unable to debug ths on my own. My instance is "g4dn.4xlarge" . I have followed the tutorial on https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2019/07/computer-vision-implementing-mask-r-cnn-image-segmentation/ My code is as follows

```
import os
import sys
import random
import math
import numpy as np
import skimage.io
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mrcnn import utils
import mrcnn.model as modellib
from mrcnn import visualize
from samples.coco import coco

COCO_MODEL_PATH = "/home/jetson/Desktop/pano_l515/Mask_RCNN/mask_rcnn_coco.h5"

class InferenceConfig(coco.CocoConfig):
    # Set batch size to 1 since we'll be running inference on
    # one image at a time. Batch size = GPU_COUNT * IMAGES_PER_GPU
    GPU_COUNT = 1
    IMAGES_PER_GPU = 1

config = InferenceConfig()
config.display()


# Create model object in inference mode.
model = modellib.MaskRCNN(mode="inference", model_dir='mask_rcnn_coco.hy', config=config)

# Load weights trained on MS-COCO
model.load_weights('mask_rcnn_coco.h5', by_name=True)

# COCO Class names
class_names = ['BG', 'person', 'bicycle', 'car', 'motorcycle', 'airplane',
               'bus', 'train', 'truck', 'boat', 'traffic light',
               'fire hydrant', 'stop sign', 'parking meter', 'bench', 'bird',
               'cat', 'dog', 'horse', 'sheep', 'cow', 'elephant', 'bear',
               'zebra', 'giraffe', 'backpack', 'umbrella', 'handbag', 'tie',
               'suitcase', 'frisbee', 'skis', 'snowboard', 'sports ball',
               'kite', 'baseball bat', 'baseball glove', 'skateboard',
               'surfboard', 'tennis racket', 'bottle', 'wine glass', 'cup',
               'fork', 'knife', 'spoon', 'bowl', 'banana', 'apple',
               'sandwich', 'orange', 'broccoli', 'carrot', 'hot dog', 'pizza',
               'donut', 'cake', 'chair', 'couch', 'potted plant', 'bed',
               'dining table', 'toilet', 'tv', 'laptop', 'mouse', 'remote',
               'keyboard', 'cell phone', 'microwave', 'oven', 'toaster',
               'sink', 'refrigerator', 'book', 'clock', 'vase', 'scissors',
               'teddy bear', 'hair drier', 'toothbrush']

# Load a random image from the images folder
image = skimage.io.imread('test_images.jpg')

# original image
plt.figure(figsize=(12,10))
skimage.io.imshow(image)

# Run detection
results = model.detect([image], verbose=1)

# Visualize results
r = results[0]
visualize.display_instances(image, r['rois'], r['masks'], r['class_ids'], class_names, r['scores'])
```

This is the error i am getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 27, in <module>
    model = modellib.MaskRCNN(mode="inference", model_dir='mask_rcnn_coco.hy', config=config)
  File "/home/ubuntu/segmentation/Mask_RCNN/mrcnn/model.py", line 1837, in __init__
    self.keras_model = self.build(mode=mode, config=config)
  File "/home/ubuntu/segmentation/Mask_RCNN/mrcnn/model.py", line 1901, in build
    stage5=True, train_bn=config.TRAIN_BN)
  File "/home/ubuntu/segmentation/Mask_RCNN/mrcnn/model.py", line 180, in resnet_graph
    x = KL.Conv2D(64, (7, 7), strides=(2, 2), name='conv1', use_bias=True)(x)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 952, in __call__
    input_list)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1091, in _functional_construction_call
    inputs, input_masks, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 822, in _keras_tensor_symbolic_call
    return self._infer_output_signature(inputs, args, kwargs, input_masks)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 862, in _infer_output_signature
    self._maybe_build(inputs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 2710, in _maybe_build
    self.build(input_shapes)  # pylint:disable=not-callable
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/convolutional.py", line 188, in build
    input_channel = self._get_input_channel(input_shape)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/convolutional.py", line 360, in _get_input_channel
    raise ValueError('The channel dimension of the inputs '
ValueError: The channel dimension of the inputs should be defined. Found `None`.
```

Comment: Did you check the shape of the image? What's the output of `image.shape`?

Comment: @Frightera (720, 1280, 3) This is the shape

Comment: config.display(), can you show what did you get for this? There should be a IMAGE_SHAPE                    [1024 1024    3]

Comment: @EdwinCheong I have added the output of config.display()